# Google's Geofence Sample Works only when other app uses gps

Tags: android, gps, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm trying to implement Geofences in my app and to do that i'm following google's sample code [available here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing) . The Problem is geofence triggering happens only when i use another application that uses gps such as maps otherwise the notification isn't displayed. Can someone tell me how to make the device keep tracking the location even when the app is closed in an efficient way.